# Problems with multi-monitor with Unity

Tags: 11.04, unity, multiple-monitors

I've installed Ubuntu 11.04 recently, and almost everythings works fine. Except when I try to use multi-monitor. The new monitor is recognized, and even show the title bar, but don't show any thing else.

I though that maybe it could be because unity is still under development, but i saw another post (right here) where people say that they hadn't have my problem.

I'm running Ubuntu in a HP G42 Notebook.

Any ideas will help me.

Regards

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the exact same issue.

I achieved to make my dual screen working after typing the following command:

```
unity --replace &
```